# How to not show foreign key ID in returned JSON?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using .NET Core 3.0 web API project. When setting up relationships, I have a model property called `ProductTypeID` which is a foreign key holding the ID of the `ProductType` table. When I query `UnitOfWork` and return this result to the controller, I wish to remove the `productTypeID` from the JSON.

ProductsController:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Product> Index()
{
    var products = _service.GetAll();

    return products;
}
```

Repository (where it eventually returns data, back to service then back to controller):

```
public override IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
{
    return _context.products
        .Include(x => x.ProductType)
        .AsEnumerable();
}
```

ProductSeeder:

```
_modelBuilder.Entity<ProductType>().HasData(new ProductType
{
    ID = 1,
    Name = "Pizza"
});

_modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(x =>
{
    x.HasOne(d => d.ProductType)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductTypeID);
});

_modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasData(
    new Product { 
        ProductTypeID = 1,
        ID = 1,
        Name = "Pepperoni",
        Price = 12m,
        Description = "Test Description"
    },
    new Product
    {
        ProductTypeID = 1,
        ID = 2,
        Name = "Margherita",
        Price = 10m,
        Description = "This is a margherita pizza"
    }
);
```

Product Model:

```
public class Product : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }


    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

Returned JSON on browser:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Pepperoni",
    "price": 12,
    "description": "Test Description",
    "productTypeID": 1,
    "productType": {
      "name": "Pizza",
      "id": 1,
      "createdAt": "20/01/2020 19:28:26",
      "updatedAt": "20/01/2020 19:28:26"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "createdAt": "20/01/2020 19:28:26",
    "updatedAt": "20/01/2020 19:28:26"
  },
  {
    "name": "Margherita",
    "price": 10,
    "description": "This is a margherita pizza",
    "productTypeID": 1,
    "productType": {
      "name": "Pizza",
      "id": 1,
      "createdAt": "20/01/2020 19:28:26",
      "updatedAt": "20/01/2020 19:28:26"
    },
    "id": 2,
    "createdAt": "20/01/2020 19:28:26",
    "updatedAt": "20/01/2020 19:28:26"
  }
]
```

I believe if I create a `ViewModel` and return this with only the properties I need, this will work. But I would like to know if there is a way I can do this without creating a `ViewModel`.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a view model? This is the exact reason view models exist.

Comment: You should avoid using your database model as data transfer objects. This can be very harmful depending on what you do. It’s best to create separate types and properly map between the types as necessary, while validating input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead with the idea of creating a view model for each database entity. This just seems to be the best approach. Then I use AutoMapper to map the properties to the viewmodel. Thank you to everyone who commented.

Answer (score 0):

You could add [`JsonIgnore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=netcore-3.0) property to remove the `productTypeID` from the JSON:

```
public class Product:BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I remember trying to add the [JsonIgnore] attribute and it did not work. I will try again and tell you exactly what happens as this was a about a week ago I tried this. Thanks

Comment: Could you show your Startup.cs?And be sure that do not mix `System.Text.Json` with `Newtonsoft.Json`.